# MochaTest error - UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: done is not a function

Tags: mongodb, npm, mocha.js

I am testing creating a user in a mongoDBusing Mocha. the following is the test to create the user. **The main issue is I get 2 errors while runnig npm test on this: 
1. the terminal stalls/lags and never finishes the test. 
2. An error is thrown: "(node:21233) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: done is not a function" Am I handling the promise wrong with done?**

Directory structure 
project

```
|-> src
   ->user.js
|-> project
   ->create_test.js
   ->test_helper.js
```

**create_test.js**

```
//startoffile
const assert = require('assert');

const User = require ('../src/user');


describe('Creating records', () => {
  it('saves a user', () => {
    //run an assertion: validate data
    let joe = new User({ name: 'Joe' });

    joe.save().then( (done) => {
      assert(!joe.isNew);
      done();
    });

  });

});

//endoffile
```

It references the user.js file to create a user.

**user.js**

```
//startoffile

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
});

var User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;

//endoffile
```

Also, there is a helper file that includes some hooks which are testing the connection and dropping all data in a table.

**test_helper.js**

```
//startoffile

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

before( (done) => {
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/users_test');
  mongoose.connection
  .once('open', () => { done(); })
  .on('error', (error) => {
    console.warn('Warning', error);
  });
});


beforeEach((done) => {
   mongoose.connection.collections.users.drop(
     () => {
       done();
     });


});

//endoffile
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at your stack trace, you should see that it's coming from the `done` in below `it` block because you're not passing it into the `it` callback. (so instead it should read `it('saves a user', (done) => {`)

```js
describe('Creating records', () => {
  it('saves a user', () => {
    //run an assertion: validate data
    let joe = new User({ name: 'Joe' });

    joe.save().then( (done) => {
      assert(!joe.isNew);
      done();
    });

  });

});
```

`mocha` does support promises, so you could rewrite that code to return promises (rather than using `done`).

```js
it('saves a user', () => {
  let joe = new User({name: 'Joe'});
  return joe.save()
    .then(() => assert(!joe.isNew));
});
```

Or if you're using `async/await`:

```js
it('saves a user', async () => {
  let joe = new User({name: 'Joe'});
  await joe.save()
  assert(!joe.isNew);
});
```

Comment: Woah, good to know! I'll keep this in mind when testing with mocha. Thanks Willis!